# To_param or slug doesn't work when rendering JSON from RoR backend

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a Ruby backend and React frontend. In my Ruby app there is a model Game. This model has a some king of a pretty URL --> like "http://localhost:3000/games/**BT526**" instead of "http://localhost:3000/games/**2**". BT526 is a :code -- string inside Game model. It works pretty good in Ruby, but when I render it to JSON and fetch it in my frontend app, links to Game just don't work. I assume, that problem is that slug is "NULL" in my JSON, but I am not sure. How can I make this modified URL work after fetching? :_(

game.rb

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    def to_param
        code
    end
    has_many :players
    has_many :monsters
end
```

games_controller.rb

```
PREFACE      = ('A'..'Z').to_a << ?_
SUFFIX       = ('0'..'9').to_a
PREFACE_SIZE = 2
SUFFIX_SIZE  = 3

class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /games or /games.json
  def index
    @games = Game.all
    render json: @games, include: [:players, :slug]
  end

  # GET /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def show
    # @game = Game.find_by_slug(params[:code])
    # @game = Game.all
    @game = set_game

    render json: @game
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(game_url)
  end

  # GET /games/new
  def new
    @game = Game.new
    @game.code = gen_name
  end

  def gen_name
    PREFACE.sample(PREFACE_SIZE).join << SUFFIX.sample(SUFFIX_SIZE).join
  end

  # GET /games/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /games or /games.json
  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.update(game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def destroy
    @game.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url, notice: "Game was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_game
      @game = Game.find_by_slug(params[:code])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:code, :name, :fight)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :effects
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :games do
    resources :players
    resources :monsters
  end
  get 'effects/index'
  get 'games/index'

  post "", to: "welcome#redirect", as: :redirect

  root 'welcome#index'

  scope '/api/v1' do
    resources :games 
    resources :players
    resources :effects
    resources :slug
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

schema.rb/game

```
  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "code"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "fight", default: false
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_games_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

And rendered json just in case:

```
[{"id":1,"code":"KR984","name":"Hello world","created_at":"2022-12-02T13:34:51.992Z","updated_at":"2022-12-07T10:32:35.827Z","slug":null,"fight":false,"players":[{"id":1,"name":"PLAYER 1","initiative":null,"hp":20,"languages":"sjdads","perc":"12","inv":"12","ins":"12","armor":44,"conc":true,"created_at":"2022-12-11T17:18:33.745Z","updated_at":"2022-12-11T17:18:33.745Z","game_id":1}]},{"id":2,"code":"BT526","name":"Random game","created_at":"2022-12-07T10:14:16.948Z","updated_at":"2022-12-07T10:14:16.948Z","slug":null,"fight":false,"players":[]}]
```

Comment: This code badly needs cleanup and you probally need coffee. You're mixing `slug` and `code` whilly nilly here. Which is it that you actually want to use?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is basically just adding an additional unique identifier to the record besides the surrogate key (the id column) to be used as the external identifier. This is a known problem with established solutions such as [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

You have really overcomplicated the whole thing and confused yourself by creating two different columns for the same thing. Pick one. If you want to alias it later do so but make sure you document it.

Then you should move the generation of the unique identifier out of the controller and into the model (or even a separate service object).

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  PREFACE      = ('A'..'Z').to_a << ?_
  SUFFIX       = (0..9).to_a
  PREFACE_SIZE = 2
  SUFFIX_SIZE  = 3

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates :code, uniqueness: true, 
                   presence: true
  has_many :players
  has_many :monsters
  
  def to_param
    code
  end

  # Generates a unique random code (hopefully) consisting of 
  # three letters and three numbers
  def generate_code
    loop do
      random_code = PREFACE.sample(PREFACE_SIZE).join << SUFFIX.sample(SUFFIX_SIZE).join
      break random_code unless self.class.exists?(code: random_code)
    end
  end

  def generate_code!
     self.code = generate_code
  end
end
```

This lets you test it isolation and you're not polluting the global namespace with constants.

You should also ensure that you're actually generating a unique code due to the pigeon hole principle. However unlikely a collision may seem it can still occur - especially when you reinvent the wheel.

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_game, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /games or /games.json
  def index
    @games = Game.all
    render json: @games, include: [:players, :slug]
  end

  # GET /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def show
    # You should probally just generate the QR code once when creating the record
    # instead of doing it over and over
    @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new(game_url(@game)) 
    render json: @game
  end

  # GET /games/new
  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  # GET /games/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /games or /games.json
  def create
    @game = Game.new(game_params)
    @game.generate_code! # Do you actually need or want the user to be able assign the code?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.save
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @game.update(game_params)
        format.html { redirect_to game_url(@game), notice: "Game was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @game }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /games/1 or /games/1.json
  def destroy
    @game.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to games_url, notice: "Game was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_game
      # params[:id] doesn't mean the id column 
      # it means the unique external identifier used in the route.
      @game = Game.find_by_code(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def game_params
      params.require(:game).permit(:name, :fight)
    end
end
```